# Postgresql function returning number of records

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, postgresql-9.4, record-count

I would like to create a function returning the number of records that an SQL expression passed as parameter can generate. Can anyone put me on the right path?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code you've tried so far!

Comment: At the very least you need to better specify what the function should do. For example, `function F takes params K, L, N. Given table A has rows (r1, r2, r3), F(k, l, n)  should return X, and F(k2, l2, n2) should return X2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain SQL you can get the number of returned rows using a derived table (placing the query in a subquery in the `FROM` clause) like this:

```
select count(*)
from (
    <your query>
    ) s;
```

Do the same in a plpgsql function. You need a [dynamic command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) as the function should work for any valid SQL query:

```
create or replace function number_of_rows(query text)
returns bigint language plpgsql as $$
declare
    c bigint;
begin
    execute format('select count(*) from (%s) s', query) into c;
    return c;
end $$;
```

Example:

```
select number_of_rows('select * from generate_series(1, 3)');

 number_of_rows 
----------------
              3
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanyou klin I followed your directions and it works perfectly!   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your function should return a `SETOF` some (record) type.
You then use the `RETURN NEXT` syntax to return each row.

See the example in the doc page for this.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.3.4